# iOS での文字入力時に表示されるコンテキストメニューに機能を追加するには？

Tags: ios

iPhoneで文章を入力する時に出てくる「コピー」や「すべてを選択」などと表示されている箇所に新しい機能を追加したいのですがどうすればいいのでしょうか？
おそらく Xcode で Swift を使って作ると思うのですが、いまいちやり方がわかりません。

ちなみに使用できる言語は Swift, Python の二つだけです。

Comment: 現在のタイトルは、iphone, xcode, swiftなど、タグでも示せる情報の他には何も意味のある情報が含まれていません。うまく要約できなければ、少し長くなってもいいですから、具体的に質問内容がわかるようにタイトルをつけた方が「それなら解決できる」と思っている人に見つけてもらいやすくなりますし、同じ点をわからないと感じている方にも有用な情報となるでしょう。ただ、「使用できる言語はswift,pythonの二つだけ」とだけしか書かれていないと、あなたが何をどこまでわかっているのか測りかねます。例えば、「文章を入力する」画面のあるアプリはXcode上で作成できるのでしょうか? ご自分が書かれたコード(ほとんどXcodeのテンプレートのままでも)を示されると、回答が書きやすくなるので、回答が付く率も高くなりますし、その内容もご自身が使いやすいものになるでしょう。

Comment: タイトルについては私が見直してみましたので、次回以降の参考にしてもらえればと思います。 / やろうとしているものと **"似た機能のアプリ"** が既に存在するか否かを調べてみるとよさそうですが、一方で恐らくは OS の機能になるのでセキュリティを理由に制限がかかっていそうだなとも考えられます。